# Map same source type against multiple target types based on a discriminator

Tags: c#, .net, mapping, automapper

Say I've a class like this one:

```
public class A
{
   public IDictionary<string, object> Arguments { get; } = new Dictionary<string, object>
   {
       ["entity"] = "teams"
   }

   public string PropertyA { get; set; }
   public string PropertyB { get; set; }
}
```

And I want to map it to `B`, `C`, `D` types based on `Arguments["entity"]`:

```
config.CreateMap<A, B>();
config.CreateMap<A, C>();
config.CreateMap<A, D>();
```

Is there any way I could accomplish this using *AutoMapper*?

Comment: How would you expect to use this? Not really sure what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @DavidG Maybe passing such discriminator as argument when performing the mapping... I'm not sure now.

Comment: But surely you still need to know the destination type when doing the mapping? For example `var newObject = Mapper.Map<OldType, ???>(currentObject)`? (can't remember the syntax now, been a while since I used AutoMapper!)

Comment: @DavidG Well, it can be autoinferred from usage. But this isn't the issue. During the mapping configuration you would give some discriminator like `config.CreateMap<A, B>().UsingDiscriminator(source => source.Args["entity"])` and later you would do this: `mapper.Map<A, B>(source => source.Args["entity"])`. Who knows, I didn't find if AutoMapper can handle something like this.

Comment: But I'm saying you can't infer it from the usage, you need to tell AutoMapper what the destination type is going to be, and what type would the mapping function actually return?

Answer (score 0):

We need a more realistic use case. But if you feel this is close enough, the solution is to create the destination object yourself and then map into an existing object. Usually things like this are handled with Include. But you need a source and destination hierarchy for that. See also [this](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/2253).